# Batch file for renaming files (+subfolders)

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I tried to rename a bunch of files (also in subfolders) in order to make movie files recognizable for my media playback system (Plex).

Before:

'TBBT - **Season 06 Episode 09** - The Parking Spot Escalation.mkv'

After: 'TBBT - **S06E09** - The Parking Spot Escalation.mkv'

I'd like to rename complete shows with just 1 click, so essentially I'm trying to change

> 'Season ' to 'S' and 'Episode ' to 'E'

Here is what I tried:

```
for /r %%x in (*Season 0* Episode 0*) do ren "%%x" *S0*E0*
```

With trying to substitute the spaces with underscores first I only got some mixup result:
'TBBT_-_Season_06_Episode_09_-_The_Parking_S**0**ot_E**0**calation'

Unfortunately I'm stuck here...

Comment: Do you have to use batch or would a Python approch fit for you, too?

Comment: Depends on how easy it is to understand the Python Approach.
I never used python until now, so this would be something entirely new for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "Pattern1=Season "
Set "Pattern2= Episode "
Set "Replace1=S"
Set "Replace2=E"

For %%# in ("C:\Folder\*.mkv") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern1%=%Replace1%!"
    echo %File%
)
For %%# in ("C:\Folder\*.mkv") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern2%=%Replace2%!"
```

And it's even easier using powershell if you want:

```
dir "c:\Folder" -file -recurse | rename-item -NewName {$_.name.Replace('Season ','S').replace(' Episode ', 'E')}
```

Comment: To simplify it, I used a txt file with:  
`Set "Pattern1=old text "
Set "Replace1=new text"

For %%# in ("C:\Users\XRAY\Desktop\Batch\Test\t2\*.txt") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern1%=%Replace1%!"
)`

I get the error message: 'A duplicate file name exists,  or the file cannot be found'.

The PowerShell Approach works, but not for subfolders.

Comment: @XRAY Try the edited powershell command with recursion - do it on copies of your files as a test first.

Comment: equinox93: your batch code is missing delayed expansion but it needs a note to say that all `!` characters will cause failures - and that is a common character in titles.

Answer (score 0):

Since a Python approach seems to be acceptable due to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296483/batch-file-for-renaming-files-subfolders?noredirect=1#comment52473324_32296483) here it is.

Assuming the directory structure is like the following:

```
.
├── Season1Episode1.mkv
├── Season2Episode2.mkv
└── subfolder
    ├── Season1Episode1.mkv
    └── Season2Episode2.mkv
```

After running the Python script given below, files are renamed as desired:

```
.
├── S1E1.mkv
├── S2E2.mkv
└── subfolder
    ├── S1E1.mkv
    └── S2E2.mkv
```

The Python3 script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import os

# rename files or just see how files would be renamed?
DRY_RUN = True

# specify file extension and replacements
EXTENSION = '.mkv'
REPLACE = [('Season', 'S'), ('Episode', 'E')]

# walk through directory and handle files
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(EXTENSION):
            full_path = os.path.join(path, name)
            new_path = full_path
            for i in REPLACE:
                new_path = new_path.replace(i[0], i[1])
            print('{} --> {}'.format(full_path, new_path))
            if not DRY_RUN:
                os.rename(full_path, new_path)
```

The script should be saved and executed in the root directory containing the files to rename. Despite of Python3 nothing additional should be needed. Set `DRY_RUN = True` in order to simulate renaming files, whereas `DRY_RUN = False` would rename the files found.